# How to assign a delegate for UITextField after initialization?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xib

New to xcode, when creating UI components in the XIB using drag/drop, where does XCode declare and allocate code for these components?

```
//where the heck are you?
UITextField* textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame: myFrame];
```

I checked the XIB, but it's just XML; checked all other source files, can't find it, so I must be missing something.

I'm asking because I need to add a delegate to my `UITextField`, after the text field is allocated. I tried doing this in `initWithNibName`, but it didn't work:

```
textField.delegate = self;
```

Comment: First of all - its really a nice Question. I have been developing for iOS for more than 1.5 yrs, but never thought where are components allocated if u wire up in xib ;)

Comment: secondly, your components are allocated after your main view. So set `myTextField.delegate = self;` in viewDidLoad rather than `initWithNibName` since at that time your main view is not allocated.

Comment: I hope whenever your viewcontroller instance get allocated at the time those xib components may get initialised, I guess so not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I too face the same problem. If i Put this line in ViewDidLoad method it works fine for me. Try like this..

```
myTextField.delegate = self;
```

Answer (score 1):

You might imported UIKit framework `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>`. Inside UIKit all the UIElements are defined. Check this [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIKit_Framework/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006955)

Comment: Not sure I follow, those are just header files, I'm looking for where the components that I've adding to my XIB are declared and allocated for use in my project.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldnt it work if you create an IBOutlet for that element ? and then assigning the delegate to it?

Comment: I have an IBOutlet for the text field; as a test, I assigned the delegate in an action method, it worked, but it was a hack. I think the `ViewDidLoad` will work.

Answer (score 1):

**The Object Loading Process:**

When you use the methods of NSNib or NSBundle to load and instantiate the objects in a nib file, the underlying nib-loading code does the following:

It loads the contents of the nib file and any referenced resource files into memory:

==>The raw data for the entire nib object graph is loaded into memory but is not unarchived.

==>Any custom image resources associated with the nib file are loaded and added to the Cocoa image cache; see “About Image and Sound Resources.”

==>Any custom sound resources associated with the nib file are loaded and added to the Cocoa sound cache; see “About Image and Sound Resources.”

It unarchives the nib object graph data and instantiates the objects. How it initializes each new object depends on the type of the object and how it was encoded in the archive. The nib-loading code uses the following rules (in order) to determine which initialization method to use.

==>By default, objects receive an `initWithCoder:` message.
In OS X, the list of standard objects includes the views, cells, menus, and view controllers that are provided by the system and available in the default Xcode library. It also includes any third-party objects that were added to the library using a custom plug-in. Even if you change the class of such an object, Xcode encodes the standard object into the nib file and then tells the archiver to swap in your custom class when the object is unarchived.

In iOS, any object that conforms to the `NSCoding` protocol is initialized using the `initWithCoder:` method. This includes all subclasses of UIView and UIViewController whether they are part of the default Xcode library or custom classes you define.

==>Custom views in OS X receive an `initWithFrame:` message.
Custom views are subclasses of NSView for which Xcode does not have an available implementation. Typically, these are views that you define in your application and use to provide custom visual content. Custom views do not include standard system views (like NSSlider) that are part of the default library or part of an integrated third-party plug-in.

When it encounters a custom view, Xcode encodes a special NSCustomView object into your nib file. The custom view object includes the information it needs to build the real view subclass you specified. **At load time, the NSCustomView object sends an alloc and `initWithFrame:` message to the real view class and then swaps the resulting view object in for itself.** The net effect is that the real view object handles subsequent interactions during the nib-loading process.

**Custom views in iOS do not use the `initWithFrame:` method for initialization.**

==>Custom objects other than those described in the preceding steps receive an init message.

For detailed explanation you can read apple documentation: [**at here..**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html)

Answer (score 0):

For that u need the include the  the basic from frame work such as #import  in ur . h file 
For example if you are using a  text field  then
you need to declare property and map in your . h file as  below

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *txtNote;

for text field you need to add its delegate method too.

by using this you can map the text view once its done

in your .m file you need to declare @synthesize txtNote; below the @implementation

once its done there is no need to allocate anything but make sure that you release

menory once you leave from the page usig [txtNote release] in dealloc - (void)dealloc method

Comment: Basically u need to add the property in .h file to each element that your using in your Xib and release the memory